# magento 2.3 customer tax class not showing on product page

Tags: tax-class, magento2.3.3

this is my general setup for taxes:

[image: general setup for taxes]

it works perfectly for customer in the retail customer class. However, I have a few customers who needs to have no tax applied to them. So I've created a new customer tax class, applied this tax class to the wholesale customer group and placed these few customers into the wholesale group. This is my tax rules setup:

[image]

these are my customer groups:

[image]

this is my test customer with the wholesale group assignment:

[image]

I created a test product with price = 50. If I open the product page from frontend, I can see the price as 50. When I add it to the cart, I can see the total correctly: subtotal 40.98 plus taxes. So far, everything works as intended: the price in catalog page shows the price including taxes and the totals shows the net price + the tax separately.

The problem is when I login as the wholesale customer:

- in the cart I see everything correctly: price 40.98, subtotal 40.98 + 0 taxes:

[image]

- but in the product page, I still see 50 as the product price: shouldn't it be 40.98 since the wholesale customer has no tax applied?

I also tried to change the basic tax setup from "including tax" to "excluding tax" for catalog prices but that doesn't seem to change anything: even with excluding tax from catalog prices, the price displayed in the product page is still 50.

Cleaning cache and reindexing doesnt help: the price in catalog page is still 50.

How can I have the price in product page show it correctly for the wholesale customer?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, this is fixed for Magento 2.4 but still exist for version 2.3.
You can fix by updating this file: `Magento/Tax/Model/Config.php`

```
public function needPriceConversion($store = null)
    {
        $res = false;
        $priceIncludesTax = $this->priceIncludesTax($store) || $this->getNeedUseShippingExcludeTax();
        if ($priceIncludesTax) {
            switch ($this->getPriceDisplayType($store)) {
                case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_EXCLUDING_TAX:
                case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_BOTH:
                    return self::PRICE_CONVERSION_MINUS;
                case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_INCLUDING_TAX:
                    $res = $this->displayCartPricesInclTax($store);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch ($this->getPriceDisplayType($store)) {
                case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_INCLUDING_TAX:
                case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_BOTH:
                    return self::PRICE_CONVERSION_PLUS;
                case self::DISPLAY_TYPE_EXCLUDING_TAX:
                    $res = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($res === false) {
            $res = $this->displayCartPricesBoth();
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26014

Comment: This did the trick for me on 2.3.4. Thanks! Seems to be fixed in 2.3.5